# Why should a tag interface appear last in a generic class declaration?

Tags: java, generics

This is an extract from *Core Java*(Volume 1,by Cay S. Hortsman).
Here we have

```
class Interval<T extends  Comparable & Serializable>
```

As it goes as:"
NOTE:You may wonder what happens if you switch the bounds:

```
class Interval<T extends Serializable & Comparable>
```

In that case, the raw type replaces T with Serializable, and the compiler inserts casts to Comparable when necessary.
 **For efficiency,** you should therefore put tagging interfaces (that is, interfaces without methods) at the end of the bounds list.
"
I have no idea why tagging interface help with efficiency and I wish a plain answer.

Comment: (More importantly, it makes a binary compatibility change. So don't switch them around and follow conventions. (Also, don't leave `Comparable` raw like that!).)

Answer (score 4):

Assuming what Mr. Horstmann says is still true, there could be a very slight efficiency difference.

Everywhere you refer to an instance as a `Comparable` (i.e. to invoke one of its methods) the compiler has to insert a runtime type check (i.e. a cast) to verify that the object is indeed a `Comparable`.  So putting the tag interface last lets the compiler check the proper type at compile time and omit the casts.

But you'd likely never notice the difference in execution speed.

Answer (score 2):

Tagging interfaces themselves do not help with efficiency.  **Putting them *last*** does, if you must include them for some other reason.

The reason putting them last helps efficiency is that when the compiler builds the "raw" type, it'll use the first available type in the type parameter list as the working type of any variable you used of that parameter type.

Thus, in this example with `<T extends Comparable & Serializable>` if you had some code that said

```
void doStuff(T t1, T t2) {
    t1.compareTo(t2);
    // more code
}
```

The compiler can translate that to

```
void doStuff(Comparable t1, Comparable t2) {
    t1.compareTo(t2);
    // more code
}
```

However, if you switch the types to `<T extends Serialazable & Comparable>` Then for the above code the compiler has to build this:

```
void doStuff(Serializable t1, Serializable t2) {
    ((Comparable)t1).compareTo((Comparable)t2));
    // more code
}
```

Those extra casts don't come for free, so to make your code as efficient as possible, if you must include a "tagging interface" (like `Serializable` for example), then you should make it the last type.

As pointed out by @biziclop, the key here is that `Comparable` is used more often than `Serializable`.  So put it first.  You *know* that `Comparable` will be used more often because `Serializable` provides no methods of its own -- there's almost no reason at all to ever want to treat a variable as being that type.

Comment: The key here is that `Comparable` is "used" far more often than `Serializable`. There are very few (if any) places where an explicit cast to `Serializable` is done, while methods that accept parameters of type `Comparable` are used all the time.

Answer (score 2):

In accordance with what others are saying, I wanted to post a bytecode example to illustrate the actual difference.

Given the following example:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

class Example<T extends Comparable<T> & Serializable> {

    int compare(T a, T b) {
        return a.compareTo(b);
    }
}
```

The `compare` method results in the following bytecode:

```
int compare(T a, T b) {
    b_start:
    a_start:
    this_start:
    Example this (#0 0 - 8)
    Comparable a (#1 0 - 8)
    Comparable b (#2 0 - 8)
    aload_1 a
    aload_2 b
    invokeinterface int Comparable.compareTo(Object) 2
    ireturn
    b_end:
    a_end:
    this_end:
}
```

Switching `Comparable<T>` and `Serializable` in the class declaration results in the addition of a single instruction, `checkcast`:

```
int compare(T a, T b) {
    b_start:
    a_start:
    this_start:
    Example this (#0 0 - 11)
    Serializable a (#1 0 - 11)
    Serializable b (#2 0 - 11)
    aload_1 a
    checkcast Comparable // right here
    aload_2 b
    invokeinterface int Comparable.compareTo(Object) 2
    ireturn
    b_end:
    a_end:
    this_end:
}
```